# Crash on creating content type?

Tags: nodes

I'm working on a D7.27 site I've inherited and when adding a new content type I'm getting this error:

```
DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table 
<em class="placeholder">field_data_body</em> already exists. 
in DatabaseSchema->createTable() (line 657 of 
/blah/docroot/includes/database/schema.inc).
```

All I've provided is the new name and clicked Save. It seems to have created the type, but without the Body field (!).

I've deleted the content type and tried again, and it's quite reproduceable! I have never encountered this error before, any ideas?

### Edit

In case this helps.

```
mysql> select field_name, count(*) 
       FROM field_config 
       WHERE field_name LIKE "%body%" GROUP BY field_name;
+-------------------------------+----------+
| field_name                    | count(*) |
+-------------------------------+----------+
| field_blog_taxonomy_term_body |        1 |
| field_body                    |        1 |
+-------------------------------+----------+

mysql> show tables like "%body%";
+----------------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_drupal (%body%)                    |
+----------------------------------------------+
| field_data_body                              |
| field_data_field_blog_taxonomy_term_body     |
| field_data_field_body                        |
| field_data_field_email_share_body            |
| field_revision_body                          |
| field_revision_field_blog_taxonomy_term_body |
| field_revision_field_body                    |
| field_revision_field_email_share_body        |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Sounds very much like someone's been fiddling around in the field_config table. I.e. The body entry has been removed manually but the field tables are still there

Comment: `field_name = "field_body"` still exists in that table. They use Features a lot. Any clues for fixing?

Comment: Ah, maybe a rogue feature then. Difficult to debug without seeing all the code. What about field_config_instance though, maybe an entry has been removed from there somehow? If there are no references to body in there, and the field data/revision tables still exist, that would cause exactly this problem when it tries to create a new instance (in that case the tables shouldn't exist as they should have been converted to deleted tables to be purged on cron)

Comment: I found `field_data_body` and `field_revision_body` tables with nothing in them, so I `DROP TABLE`d them. Now it works. Odd.

Comment: I ran into this issue when I deleted the body field from the only content type that was on there.  So creating a new content type it attempts to add the body that isn't there